Mail Rules for Hide My Email?
How can I make a Rule in macOS Mail app (Version 16.0) to filter messages sent to any "Hide My Email" address?

Which version of the mail app do you hope to make this rule?

Version 16.0 (3776.700.51)

You ask about how to filter any Hide my Email mails, but based on your comments beneath the answer explaining how to filter you seem to want to do more than just filter. Can you add some details about what you want to with those mails and why Apples support documentation doesn’t help in your case?

In macOS Mail app, I can open the app’s settings, and under the “Rules” tab, I can click “Add Rule”. From there, I can filter based on many “conditions”, such as whether “From” “contains” or “doesn’t contain” or “begins with” etc any text, or similar for “To”, “CC”, etc, and two dozen more conditions. But I don’t see how among these conditions I can filter for emails that are sent to me through “Hide My Email”.
